# On Windows, how to check that data is unchanged after copying?

Tags: windows, data-transfer

Suppose I have large number of files, I copied them to a different location, I want to check all files are properly copied or not, their contents are they corrupted or not. I want to check it on both Linux and Windows. How should I be able to do the same?

Comment: Most contemporary file systems (including network ones like smb and nfs) verify as they go.   What did you use?

Comment: I do use TeraCopy or Robocopy or rsync for network transfers because they perform more robust verifications that the standard windows copy. They all use Hashes or checksums of file data to confirm that the files data is the same on both ends.

Comment: Search for "md5 hash"

Answer (score 0):

For post-copy file integrity check I recommend [MultiHasher](http://www.abelhadigital.com/multihasher). (Is it okay to recommend software in an answer?) It's minimalist design. Just drag and drop files/folders into the main window and wait for **hash**es to be generated. A **hash** value is a unique string that changes if and only if file content changes.

To verify copied files on-the-go you can use command-line solution like:

```
copy /V C:\abc.exe C:\xyz.exe
```

The parameter `/v` explicitly tells Windows to check for each file copied for integrity. I think Windows is smart enough to do this when you copy from Explorer but hence explicitly, do it with command-line and add `/v`.